# How to pass information from Twig to Javascript using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, symfony, twig

twig :

```
    {% for i in score %}
    <canvas class="credsEarned">
    <div id="test" data-is-test="{{ i.pts|json_encode }}">
    </div>
    </canvas>
    {% endfor %}
```

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var contexts = $('.credsEarned');
    for(var i = 0;i<contexts.length;i++){ 
        var data = $('#test').data("isTest");
var context = contexts.get(i).getContext('2d');
}
});
```

result :

only the first variable in the twig loop is consecutively retrived

using this doc https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/server-data.html

i modified my code but still it's the same outcome

twig :

```
{% for i in score %}
<canvas class="credsEarned">
<div class="js-user-rating" data-is-authenticated="{{ i.pts }}"></div>
</canvas>
{% endfor %}
```

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var contexts = $('.credsEarned');
    for(var i = 0;i<contexts.length;i++){
        var userRating = document.querySelector('.js-user-rating');
        var data = userRating.dataset.isAuthenticated;
}
});
```

Comment: IDs are unique, creating multiple elements with the same id (as you do in your loop) lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @ccKep is right, you should change the id for a class and then query for it inside the canvas element.

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't put JSON inside an html attribute as JSON contains quotes for keys/values and could mess up the html syntax

Comment: @PatrickEvans then how else can i pass dynamic information from my twig to javascript ? sorry i'm learning

Comment: @MarkE can i see how please ? i'm new and have no clue about JSON

Comment: @ccKep what is the correct way of doing this please ?

Comment: Change this query `document.querySelector('.js-user-rating');` for this one `$(contexts[i]).find('.js-user-rating')` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how big your script is, but  you could put it in the template to set the variable using twig.

```
{% for i in score %}
    <canvas class="credsEarned">
        <div class="js-user-rating"></div>
    </canvas>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var dataArray = [
            {% for i in score -%}
                {{ i.pts|json_encode }},
            {% endfor -%}
        ];

        var contexts = $('.credsEarned');
        for(var i = 0;i<contexts.length;i++){ 
            var data = dataArray[i];
            var context = contexts.get(i).getContext('2d');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I made it simple for comprehension but of course you could put the script in a twig block to load it at the bottom of the page.

---

If you can't (or don't want to) separate this part of your script from the rest in order to put it in the template, you could just set the data in a global variable in the template and use it in your javascript file when document is ready:

Twig:

```
{% for i in score %}
    <canvas class="credsEarned">
        <div class="js-user-rating"></div>
    </canvas>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    dataArray = [
        {% for i in score -%}
            {{ i.pts|json_encode }},
        {% endfor -%}
    ];
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var contexts = $('.credsEarned');
        for(var i = 0;i<contexts.length;i++){ 
            var data = dataArray[i];
            var context = contexts.get(i).getContext('2d');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work i only get the last variable this way and i was getting the first before, also i should point out my js code is not inside the twig but inside another file

Comment: @Megumin this is only an example of what could be accomplished.. You still need to do something with the variables in the `for`-loop obvious

Comment: @Megumin Have you seen and tested my updated code? Have you tried outputting the `dataArray` variable to the console? It should contain more than the last item.

Comment: @Megumin I added a way for you to keep your main script in a separate file and still get the data from the template.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is that you don't use the indice **i** to select your *js-user-rating*, is that normal ? I think that why you have always the first element.

may be, you can do like :

```js
for(var i = 0;i<contexts.length;i++){
  var context = contexts[i]
  var userRating = context.find('.js-user-rating');
  var data = userRating.dataset.isAuthenticated;
  ...
}
```